# GPU usage and heat production in linux

Tags: linux, laptop, fedora, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu

I am using Fedora 18 in my laptop with Nvidia GT 630M graphics card. I am using dual boot with windows 7.

In windows I am getting a battery backup of around 3 hr. But when I use Fedora, it reduces to 1 hr. It also produces excess heat.

After searching a lot on power saving, I used many tools like powertop. But it doesn't make any difference.

Then I came to know that nvidia GPUs are poorly supported in Linux and it can produce high heat due to excess use of GPU.

So below is the data I got on GPU usage from powertop.

[image]

Does this value denote a high GPU usage ? How can I reduce this problem for a better battery backup and lesser heat production?

**UPDATE (PROBLEM SOLVED)**:

I followed @allquixotic answer and it worked. I tested my computer for temperature and battery backup.

`sensors` shows around 50 C which means **8-10 C reduction** in temperature. (ie great).

And now I get **3 hr full videoplayback** battery backup, and that is awesome (earlier it was less than 1.5 hr without videoplayback)!!!

So in short, BumbleBee works fine in Fedora 18 !!!

Comment: If any further details needed, please ask.

Comment: Are you using nouveau or the nvidia binary driver?

Comment: I think nouveau, but how can I make sure of it?

Comment: Run `glxinfo` (you may have to install mesa-utils package first)

Comment: nouveau is extremely poor at power management; if you expect even semi reasonable battery drain on linux, use the nvidia binary driver.

Comment: i got this for glxinfo : http://pastebin.com/28bhcczQ

Comment: Ah. You aren't even using your nvidia card. You're just using the on-CPU Intel GPU. That said, your Nvidia GPU is probably running at full blast because nothing told it to power down. No wonder you're suffering terrible battery life.

Comment: Come on over to [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think we have worked it out in chat: [convo starts here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9301427#9301427)

The basic idea is: Bumblebee. It's well supported on Fedora 18.

[Fedorawiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Bumblebee) has instructions.

I created a [github gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5527047) containing the appropriate commands.

The result, if it works, should be:

- Intel graphics on the processor is the primary display adapter
- When the Nvidia card isn't being used, it turns itself off (as requested by Bumblebee)
- To use the Nvidia card, you must explicitly invoke a program with the `optirun` wrapper.

Advantages:

- Power savings: Intel GPU is very low power
- Power savings: the Nvidia GPU isn't running at full blast all the time; in fact, most of the time it will be off and consuming no / very low power
- Performance: if you need extra "oomph" for a particular program, you can get it.
- Flexibility

Disadvantages:

- Proprietary Nvidia driver. >:(